# NASM: unable to open include file

Tags: include, nasm

I've seen some other questions regarding this, but none of them seem to help.
my nasm directory is:

```
NASM/
  include/
    macros/
      consoleIO.inc
      loops.inc
  test.asm
```

consoleIO.inc includes loops.inc, but when I include consoleIO.inc into test.asm and assemble it, I get the following error:
`` include/macros/consoleIO.inc:1: fatal: unable to open include file `loops.inc' ``
Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm running this on an Xubuntu VM and i assemble the program like so:
`nasm -f elf -o test.o test.asm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in [the manual](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.6.1):

> Include files are searched for in the current directory (the directory you're in when you run NASM, as opposed to the location of the NASM executable or the location of the source file), plus any directories specified on the NASM command line using the -i option.

The `-i` option is documented [here](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.18).

So you'll want to change your invocation of NASM to something like:

```
nasm -f elf -i~/NASM/include/macros/ -o test.o test.asm
```